# JavaScript new window with dynamic content and blank url, event listeners not called

Tags: javascript

Case 1:

```
var printWindow = window.open("", "print_window");
if(printWindow) {

    printWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){alert(1);}, false); //Everything works but this listener is never called

    printWindow.document.write(printView);
    printWindow.focus();
}
```

Case 2:

```
var printWindow = window.open("<html>useless random stuff</html>", "print_window");
if(printWindow) {

    printWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){alert(1);}, false); //this is hit
    printWindow.focus();
}
```

So, dynamically loading HTML to the new window document cancels the load event listener? Or am I really messing things up somewhere?
Need help :D

Answer (score 1):

You've some document context problems. Have a look up to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and [dummy examples](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Also inspect below snippet and give attention that how alert function should be called from different window namespace.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="window_opener">Click me to load a new window</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("window_opener").addEventListener('click', function(){
    var badDocumentString = "<html><head><title>print window</title></head><body>I live in child window</body></html>";
    var child = window.open()
    childdoc = child.document
    childdoc.write(badDocumentString);
    childdoc.close();
    child.addEventListener("load", function(){
      child.alert("zeee germans"); //attention here
    });
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But hey in my current setup, your snippet is not working

Comment: it works when I remove the childDoc.write() and directly pass html to window open as parameter

Comment: with chrom(e/ium), yes, i've just realized this doesn't work. try with firefox. or inject window.load = alert(your_message) to `badDocumentString` variable to make code also to work on chrome.

Comment: I have solved my primary issue so i dont think i need to proceed this childWindow load listener way....thanks anyway :)