# Why doesn't my console show a result with blank window?

Tags: javascript, html, web

The question is simple: why doesn't my console show a result based on the code below?
There is no message 'Loaded' in the console after this code has been executed... Seems like 'onload' has interaction problems with 'about:blank' window. Maybe 'about:blank' has permanent 'readyState' property which always describes 'complete'?

P.S. Tested it only in Google Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        let newWindow = window.open('about:blank')

        newWindow.onload = function() {
            console.log('Loaded')
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless the new window/tab is in the same domain that your parent is.

Comment: Look at the the answer and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130817/javascript-new-window-with-dynamic-content-and-blank-url-event-listeners-not-ca)

Comment: What is the URL of the page where you executed that script?

Comment: I've tried to execute the code on my local PC through MS Visual Code and via jsbin.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't onload event work on a tab opend with window.open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657649/why-doesnt-onload-event-work-on-a-tab-opend-with-window-open)

Comment: No, It doesnt. Unfortunately...

Comment: Copying + pasting the body of your script into Chrome dev tools JS console and running it results in the console message "Loaded", when I run it at a page on Wikipedia or MDN docs. It fails at StackOverflow. It's definitely related to [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).